# Confusion in the Python list output

Tags: python-3.x, list, for-loop

```
even=[2,4,6,8]
odd=[1,3,5,7,9]
number=[even,odd]

for i in number:
    print(i)
    for j in i:
        print(j)

[2, 4, 6, 8]
2
4
6
8
[1, 3, 5, 7, 9]
1
3
5
7
9
```

I am not able to understand the output. Can anyone explain?

Comment: Can you properly format  your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You create two lists and use them to create a `list` of lists:

```
number=[even,odd] = [[2,4,6,8], [1,3,5,7,9]]
```

Then you loop over this `list` of lists, so `i` contains each member of this `list` of  lists, which is a `list`.

```
for i in [[2,4,6,8], [1,3,5,7,9]]:
    print(i)

>> [2, 4, 6, 8]
```

Then you loop over each element of this `list`. Each element is stored in `j`.

```
for j in [2, 4, 6, 8]:
    print(j)

>> 2
>> 4
>> 6
>> 8
```